# Should I use composite primary keys in this example?

Tags: sql, composite-primary-key

I am not a SQL expert, so I defer to someone with more knowledge. So here is my question. I have designed a database where every table has an `Id` column (auto increment) that is the primary key. And I use this design without any issue - it makes sense to me I simply do referential integrity by way of this simple primary key since the Id columns of all tables uniquely identifies each row.

Some of my colleagues have suggested that I use composite primary keys, but I see no value in doing that. The purpose of a primary key is to enable referential integrity, and that is what it does.

For example, this is a toy example but it demonstrates my design:

```
tbl_Customers
-------------
Id (PK)
Code (VARCHAR)
Name (VARCHAR)
Surname (VARCHAR)

tbl_CustomerDetails
-----------------
Id (PK)
CustomerId (FK to tbl_Customers)
SomeDetails (VARCHAR)
```

This does not use a seperate 'linking' table, but it does not matter, it demonstrates my design.

Some of my colleagues noted that I should have a `composite primary key` on `tbl_Customers` to not only include Id as I do now, but also Code. They say that this will improve performance and that it will ensure that Code will not duplicate.

My counter argument is that if I want Code to not duplicate, I can create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `Code`. And that, since my front-end only ever works with Ids and never allows for example searching (SELECTing) by Code, that there can not be a performance improvement. On my presentation layer, if I show for example Customers and I allow the user to select one to see the associated CustomerDetails, I will select the corresponding tbl_CustomerDetails rows on CustomerId where it matches the selected Id of the clicked customer.

What do you suggest? Am I correct or am I wrong? I am always willing to learn, and if I am wrong here I'd love to learn. But at the moment, I do not feel their arguments are valid. Which is why I am asking the community.

Thanks!

Comment: There are passionate advocates on both sides of the debate. You're not wrong, but it's not how I'd do it.

Comment: If code doesn't need to duplicate then it needs a unique index, a composite index on `ID,Code` will allow duplicate ID's and duplicate codes, just not duplicate combinations. The question though is subjective and not suitable for SO since there is no single 'right' answer here.

Comment: I wouldn't say you need composites here but I would say that you should *enforce* your natural keys as well as your surrogates. If `Code` should be unique, mark it as so.

Comment: I am curious how your front end only works by Ids though, since they're meaningless identifiers. *somewhere* something must allow some form of mapping between "real" data and your surrogate identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to go with single column primary key instead on composite keys. The biggest drawback with composite key is that you require more than one value /columnto identify a row. If your application uses an O/RM (Object/Relation Mapping) layer, then you will have fits mapping these database rows to objects in a programming language. O/RM's are easiest to set up when every table has a single column primary key.

Programming aside,the major drawback of composite keys in general, and especially composite keys requiring this many columns, is all of this data needs to be specified and copied to child tables in order to set up proper relationships between tables which is wastage of space and it increase unnecessary complexity too.

The biggest headache I've run into with developers is they assume "uniqueness of data" equates "identifying a row in the database". This is rarely the case. I've found applications and databases to be much more maintainable and easy to build by defaulting to single column primary keys, and using composite keys as an exception to the rule, then enforcing data uniqueness by using unique constraints or indexes on those columns.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question and arguments I would like to say **you are not wrong**.
Since you have ID auto incremented which will always provides uniqueness to your row.
Now talking about `code` column, then if `code` should be unique then you can always have UNIQUE constraint for column which will not allow duplicate values for `code` and since you are doing it from front end so no need to add composite primary key with(ID,Code) but make sure you add `UNIQUE constraint` for `code` column.
You have already given explanation buddy and **I believe you are totally right**.

If you are going to make composite primary key then you have to consider two things here:

> 1. Composite PK on `(ID,Code)` will allow duplicate ID's and duplicate codes, it will not 
>       allow duplicate combinations.
> 2. you have to add **`code`** column in tbl_CustomerDetails table as well if you are going 
>       to link both tables.

**In Summary I would like to say I don't feel that in this case Composite Primary Key is required.**

Answer (score 1):

If your question is, should you use a composite key in your example, the answer to that is a resounding NO! Your colleague's suggestion to add code as a composite key is not only unnecessary but will more than likely introduce problems for you down the road.  Let me illustrate:

Let's say that you'd like to distinguish customers by code: All members are having code MEMB plus the Id number, all vendors have code VEND plus the Id number, and all customers have code CUST plus Id.
Among the "customers" are donors who don't purchase anything but give a contribution. You decide to make a distinction between donors and customers.

That means you'll have to change the code of some of your customers from CUST to DONOR plus Id. To make that change you will have to UPDATE EVERY INSTANCE of CUST that's a donor into DONOR. That could be a nightmare to say the least as you'll need to figure out every table that has that Id as a reference.

With your current set up, all you have to do is update the Code in ONE place and no more changes are needed. So you're right in your implementation.